# How to resume an activity after Animation Ends?

Tags: android, android-animation

I tried resuming activity in onAnimationEnd() but it throws a null pointer exception instead, I know I am doing something wrong can anybody please help me figure this out ?

```
 Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.my_animation);
 myLayout.startAnimation(animation);
 animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                            onResume();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                        }
                    });
```

on Debugging I found out the error occurs in the getTransformation() which leads to a NullPointerException in the Choreographer class.

P.S - I want to perform an animation and resume the activity just after the animation is over, is there any other way to achieve that ?

Comment: your activity isn't paused, so it's not resumed

Comment: learn basics https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: Thankyou @DimaRostopira :)

Answer (score 0):

When animation is happening,your activity is in resumed state only.It has not gone to pause state to resume it back. If your idea is to execute the logic written in onResume method,copy that to some other method and call it.Do not call lifecycle callbacks directly .These callbacks are called by ActivityManager properly at requied time. You should be clear about the life cycle callback of activity very thoroughly.

[Android activity and lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html)

Comment: Thankyou @HasifSeyd :)

Comment: @Udit Sarkar you thank people here with upvoting and/or accepting answers